# How many candies they have?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Pedro, Maria and Antonio have a total of 30 candies. Knowing that Pedro has three candies more than Antonio and that Maria has 6 candies less than Pedro, it can be concluded that: Maria has ________ candies and Pedro has _____ and Antonio has ____

To try to solve this i did p variable for Pedro, a for Antonio and m for Maria.

```
P=3+A
M=P-6
P+M+A=30
P+P-6+P-3=30
3P-9=30
3P=21
P=7
```

And then i got $A=4$ and $M=1$

Is my logic correct?

Comment: If maria has 6 candies less than pedro, $m=p-6$ ,no?

Comment: check line 6 of your reasoning

Comment: Since Maria has $6$ less than Pedro, you should have the equation $M=P-6$, instead of $M=P+6$. Your solution can't be right because in total they would only have $7+4+1=12$.

Comment: Oh sorry i meant m = p -6

Comment: $3p-9=30 \implies p=13$ you have written $7$

Comment: oh i substracted 9 from 30

Comment: thanks sai-kartik

Comment: No problem :) You might wanna consider starting this problem over to see if you got everything correct..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 3 variable you can do it easier like this:

Pedro $\rightarrow x$

Antonio $\rightarrow x-3$

Maria $\rightarrow x-6$

their sum is $30$ so:

$x+(x-3)+(x-6)=30   \rightarrow 3x-9=30 \rightarrow x=13$

Pedro has $13$ candies , Anotonio has $10$ and Maria has $7$ candies.